# How to prove fooling set problem to be NP-hard

Tags: reductions

I read in a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/11779148_33) showing that it can be implemented by reducing induced matching problem on bipartite graphs to fooling set. But the proof was omitted in that paper and I cannot find answer by myself.

Thank you.

**Edit:** The fooling set technique is defined by the following theorem:

[image]

Comment: Can you please identify the paper?

Comment: Finding lower bounds for Nondeterministic state complexity is hard

Comment: @Michael: I did not find a good reduction to reduce a NP-hard to fooling set. I thought CLIQUE may be a good idea, but I failed to find the gardget.

Comment: @Handman: Please define the problem!

Comment: Prove fooling set problem is NP-hard

Comment: @Handman: But what is the fooling set problem?

Comment: Using fooling set technique to find the lower bound

Comment: @Handman: I don't see how this comment answers my question. Please make an effort to define the fooling set problem in your question if you expect people to take their time to help you!

Comment: @Handman @Michael: I added the definition of the "fooling set" technique.

Comment: @Sadeq: You probably should add the problem's definition given here: http://books.google.com/books?id=mTtp6FSH3-oC&pg=PA370&lpg=PA370&dq=fooling+set+problem&source=bl&ots=kdSnkrw6PA&sig=-nFwofxzPzWHSVtVmljqcysr8T0&hl=fr&ei=TLn6TPrAJsKAlAeywaiFDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. The full (fool?!) definition of the problem, as well as the proof, comes below in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proof is given in Section 6 the [full version of the paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.85.4144). I bring an excerpt, since there was originally much confusion about what "fooling set" means.

Basically, the notion of fooling set was introduced by Jean-Camille Birget in [Intersection and union of regular languages and state complexity](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(92)90198-5).

To prove that fooling set problem (as defined below) is NP-hard, the authors reduced **the NP-complete induced matching problem on bipartite graphs** to it.

Here's an excerpt of the paper, which defines the problem and proves the theorem.

---

[image: excerpt of the paper]

Comment: Thank you very much! I see the version from google book of the proceeding papers, and seems they omitted the proof part.

Comment: @Handman: Since this is exactly the answer you were looking for, I think you should accept it!

Comment: @Handman: You're welcome, but you misunderstood me. What I meant is that you should click on the green arrow next to the answer.

Comment: @Handman: That was funny dude :)

Comment: @Michael, sorry for misunderstanding you. This is the first time I asked question.

Comment: The "official" preliminary full version is available as ECCC report ECCC TR06-027 under http://www.eccc.uni-trier.de/report/2006/027/